# Can't exec SQL stored procedure in java

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL which can run in SQL without problems. But when I use Java to call it, the code can run but stored procedure cannot be called. Here's my code:

```
public int countPV(int value){
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        conn = MyConection.getConnection();
        CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call countPV(?)}");
        cstmt.setInt(1, value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }finally{
        try {

            MyConection.closeConnection(conn, null, rs);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return 1;

}
```

And here is my stored procedure in SQL:

```
CREATE procedure countPV (@pID int)
as
begin
WHILE (2>1)
BEGIN
    update tblUser
    set countx = countx + 1
    where ID = @pID
    SET @pID = (select parentID from tblUser where ID = @pID)
    if(@pID = (select parentID from tblUser where ID = @pID))
    break;
END
end
```

Comment: so what is the error?

Comment: no error in JAVA. but store can not exec in SQL

Comment: maybe you are just missing a `commit` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `CallableStatement#execute()` in your method.

```
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call countPV(?)}");
cstmt.setInt(1, value);

cstmt.execute(); // MISSING!
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html

Since CallableStatemnt is extending PreparedStatement,it inherited it's executing methods (execute, executeQuery, executeUpdate) to be executed like normal quires.

I Would like to recommend using `setQueryTimeout` for any stored procedure calls to avoid timeout issues.